# is Epidemic Data For Novel Coronavirus COVID-19 not updated?

Tags: dataset, curated-data

I am trying to get the epidemic data of Colombia and I encounter that since May 27 there is not information about. The data which I obtained is

```
epidemicData = 
 ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]
```

[image]

But, I notice that since May 27 the corresponding values of "ConfirmedCases" are `Missing`
as is shown in the screenshot bottom

[image]

Someone knows why this happened? Thanks so much!.

Comment: I don't know that anybody here will be able to answer that, since this is completely under WRI's control.

Comment: Have you tried executing `ResourceUpdate["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]` first?